# Git: How do I put a non-bare repo with sub-modules on a server?

Tags: git

How do a take a non-bare git repo with submodules and make it suitable for installation on a server? (bare)

None of the following work:

```
git clone --bare nonBare bare
git clone --bare --recursive nonBare bare
git clone --recursive nonBare bare; cd bare; git config --bool core.bare true
```

The server is git-daemon.

Answer (score 0):

On server create a bare repo

```
mkdir bareRepo.git
cd bareRepo.git
git init --bare
```

On source non-bare repo

```
git push --mirror <bareRepo.git URL>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to pick up the submodules. I am using git version 1.7.4.1.

Comment: Note: the version of git used to create the original repos was newer, so that there are .git files with "gitdir: ..." contents.

Answer (score 0):

In turns out that there were multiple problems. Given that the git-daemon server didn't support the same representation for submodules as the repo I had, I decided to treat each submodule as a separate repo. One issue that I had to deal with was that since the existing repo had remotes for a server that I didn't have access to, I had to create new remotes for the new server. When a git push was made, only the current branch was pushed, not all of the (old) remote tracking branches.

To migrate, I wrote a script which did the following:

```
for every submodule, created a destination directory and did a "git init --bare" in it
for every submodule
  for every branch in the submodule, do a "git checkout <branch>"
  do a "git push --mirror <destination Directory>
```